# SQL not efficient enough, tuning assistance required

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have some SQL that is ok on smaller data volumes but poor once we scale up to selecting from larger volumes. Is there a faster alternative style to achieve the same output as below? The idea is to pull back a single unique row to get latest version of the data... The SQL does reference another view but this view runs very fast - so we expect the issue is here below and want to try a different approach

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   (SELECT (select CustomerId from PremiseProviderVersionsToday 
            where PremiseProviderId = b.PremiseProviderId) as CustomerId, 
            c.D3001_MeterId, b.CoreSPID, a.EnteredBy, 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.PremiseProviderId
            ORDER BY a.effectiveDate DESC) AS rowNumber
    FROM PremiseMeterProviderVersions a, PremiseProviders b, 
         PremiseMeterProviders c
    WHERE (a.TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL 
    AND a.PremiseMeterProviderId = c.PremiseMeterProviderId 
    AND b.PremiseProviderId = c.PremiseProviderId)
   ) data
WHERE data.rowNumber = 1
```

Comment: questions seeking tuning,will need to include execution plan,schema and counts of the tables involved in question

Comment: This part "PremiseMeterProviderVersions a, PremiseProviders b, PremiseMeterProviders c" means you are calling all fields in that table.. Why don't you call an specific field that you need only not to call all fields.

Comment: Have you tried using `INNER JOIN`, especially for much better clarity? Have you tried commenting out subqueries to see if one of them is the reason?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, in the end i used..
   (select top 1 CustomerId from PremiseProviderVersions where 
PremiseProviderId = b.PremiseProviderId and TransactionDateTimeEnd is null and effectivedate <= getdate()
order by EffectiveDate desc)

By removing the call to the view and going direct to the table it performs OK

Answer (score 1):

As Bilal Ayub stated above, the correlated subquery can result in performance issues. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) for more detail. Below are my suggestions:

1. Change all to explicit joins (ANSI standard)
2. Use aliases that are more descriptive than single characters (this is mostly to help readers understand what each table does)
3. Convert *data* subquery to a temp table or cte (temp tables and ctes usually perform better than subqueries)
4. Note: normally, you should explicitly create and insert into your temp table but I chose not to do that here as I do not know the data types of your columns.

   ```
   SELECT d.CustomerId
        , c.D3001_MeterId
        , b.CoreSPID
        , a.EnteredBy
        , rowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY b.PremiseProviderId ORDER BY a.effectiveDate DESC)
   INTO #tmp_RowNum
   FROM PremiseMeterProviderVersions a 
   JOIN PremiseMeterProviders        c ON c.PremiseMeterProviderId = a.PremiseMeterProviderId  
   JOIN PremiseProviders             b ON b.PremiseProviderId = c.PremiseProviderId
   JOIN PremiseProviderVersionsToday d ON d.PremiseProviderId = b.PremiseProviderId
   WHERE a.TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL

   SELECT * 
   FROM #tmp_RowNum
   WHERE rowNumber = 1
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You are running a correlated query that will run in loop, if size of table is small it will be faster, i would suggest to change it and try to join the table in order to get customerid.

(select CustomerId from PremiseProviderVersionsToday where PremiseProviderId = b.PremiseProviderId) as CustomerId

Answer (score 0):

Consider derived tables including an aggregate query that calculates maximum *EffectoveDate* by *PremiseProviderId* and unit level query, each using explicit joins (current ANSI SQL standard) and not implicit as you currently use:

```
SELECT data.*
FROM 
   (SELECT t.CustomerId, c.D3001_MeterId, b.CoreSPID, a.EnteredBy, 
           b.PremiseProviderId, a.EffectiveDate
    FROM PremiseMeterProviders c 
    INNER JOIN PremiseMeterProviderVersions a
        ON a.PremiseMeterProviderId = c.PremiseMeterProviderId 
        AND a.TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL 
    INNER JOIN PremiseProviders b
        ON b.PremiseProviderId = c.PremiseProviderId    
    INNER JOIN PremiseProviderVersionsToday t 
        ON t.PremiseProviderId = b.PremiseProviderId
   ) data
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT b.PremiseProviderId, MAX(a.EffectiveDate) As MaxEffDate
    FROM PremiseMeterProviders c 
    INNER JOIN PremiseMeterProviderVersions a
        ON a.PremiseMeterProviderId = c.PremiseMeterProviderId 
        AND a.TransactionDateTimeEnd IS NULL 
    INNER JOIN PremiseProviders b
        ON b.PremiseProviderId = c.PremiseProviderId 
    GROUP BY b.PremiseProviderId   
   ) agg
ON data.PremiseProviderId = agg.PremiseProviderId
AND data.EffectiveDate = agg.MaxEffDate
```